# Shortcut for CSS grouping elements

Tags: css

I have div with lot of input elements. I need to group couple of inputs and add them some style:

```
div#tabs_add_invoice input#id_description,
div#tabs_add_invoice input#id_annotation,
div#tabs_add_invoice input#id_other {
    /*some style definition*/
}
```

Is there any shortcut for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to assign "class" to the divs which you wish to group
Say,

```
<div id="div1" class="commonDiv"></div>
<div id="div2" class="commonDiv"></div>
<div id="div3" class="commonDiv"></div>
<div id="div4" class="commonDiv"></div>
```

Now in your CSS you need to give the stylesheet only to commonDiv

```
.commonDiv {
  //Your styling goes here
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what classes are for +1

Answer (score 2):

I see your inputs have an ID, this should make them unique, so you don't need to specify anything else like parents. As an example, `body div#content div#tabs_add_invoice input#id_description` is the same as `#id_description`. This means the following will do the same job.

```
#id_description,
#id_annotation,
#id_other {
    /*some style definition*/
}
```

or even this, but it will affect ALL inputs inside `#tabs_add_invoice`

```
#tabs_add_invoice input {
    /*some style definition*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any shortcut for that?

Yes. Use [CSS classes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to match elements instead of IDs.

Your input elements can share styles by assigning the same class. Like:

**CSS**

```
input.wideInput {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs_add_invoice">
    <input type="text" id="id_description" class="wideInput" /> 
    <input type="text" id="id_annotation" class="wideInput" /> 
    <input type="text" id="id_other" class="wideInput" />
    <input type="text" id="id_different" />
</div>
```